# What are the different methods to attain moksha?

Tags: guru

there is kriya yoga,kundalini yoga,Ucchishta ganapati,mantras given by Guru etc what else?

Comment: Simple questions you are quietesecence of Hinduism but complex answer first surrender to lord krishna through a proper madhwa tradition guru and get deeksha and 24/7 do 9 types of bakthi after several births with right knowledge of god one will get liberation